# Why properties binding (type conversion) changed in Spring 4.3.15:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I have a Spring Boot application in which I'm using a file. The file location is configured in a configuration properties file.
Since I upgraded my spring-boot version, the file cannot be found anymore.

**upgrade**

I upgraded from Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE to 1.5.11.RELEASE.
Due to that change I have a new Spring dependency (4.3.14 -> 4.3.15).

**setup**

I have a properties file (`application.yml`) which has properties that I parse with `@ConfigurationProperties` on a config Pojo. One of the attributes (called `file`) is of the type `java.io.File`.
In the properties file I use a relative path (relative to classpath (`/resources` directory)).

So I have `src/main/resources/sub/file.dat` (the file the application needs) and in my properties-file it says `..somewhere.file: "sub/file.dat"`.

In the setter of the `file` attribute (in the config class) the parameter is of type `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`.

```
public void setFile(Resource path) throws IOException {
    this.file = path.getFile();
}
```

**mapping/binding**

So, Spring takes care of the mapping between the string value in the properties (value) and the `Resource` parameter. I looked into it a bit, and it uses custom "editors" to convert the String into a Resource.
However, Resource is an interface, so the actual class that it will be mapped (bind) to is unclear.

**What changed?**

Now, with Spring Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE the Resource was a `DefaultResourceLoader$ClassPathContextResource`.
And with Spring Boot 1.5.11.RELEASE the Resource became a `ServletContextResource`.

The latter thinks differently about where to find my resources. It thinks they are in `src/main/webapp/` instead of `src/main/resources`. 
So, I actually found out what triggered the error of not being able to find my file.

**Solution**

I also found out that changing `Resource` into `ClassPathResource` solved my issue entirely.

However, I still don't understand why this could happen with a patch-release of spring-boot (in fact spring itself). Is it a bug??

I think I understand that using `Resource` as a type was a bit risky because it has so many implementations.

I can't find anything in the changelog of spring 4.3.15 (https://jira.spring.io/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&version=16633)

See also: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/custom-configuration-properties-binding.html

Comment: How are you running your Spring Boot application? As a deployed WAR or a standalone JAR? But I guess that is a result of [this change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11659) in Spring Boot. Which actually makes it work the way it should have been working according to the resource loading rules of Spring. (For a `WebApplicationContext` the root path is the root of the web application and not the root of the class path). So what you actually should have had in your properties file is `classpath:sub/file.dat` instead of what you have now.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum. Yes, I have a WAR. Thanks for the classpath idea.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your issue is caused by this change [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/3db5c70b582e3c899aea2fd5e0f5fead4d60b689) and this issue [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11659). Previously the registered ProtocolResolvers were not used, but the change caused by this commit fixed this, and it seems it affects you because of that.